# Get object attribute value after query - DJango

Tags: python, django

```
class item (models.Model):
    ITEMS = [
    ("ELEC", "ELECTRICIDAD" ),
    ("CERR", "CERRAJERÍA"),
    ("REFR", "REFRIGERACIÓN"),
    ("PLOM", "PLOMERÍA"),
    ("HERE", "HERRERÍA"),
    ("CARP", "CARPINTERÍA"),
    ("TRON", "ELECTRÓNICA"),
    ]
    DAYS_OF_WORKS = [
    ("LV", "LUNES A VIERNES"),
    ("LL", "LUNES A LUNES"),
    ]
    items = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices = ITEMS)
    certificate=models.ImageField(default=None) 
    provider = models.ForeignKey(serviceProvider, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    radius = models.FloatField(default=None)
    description= models.TextField(blank = True)
    days_of_works = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices= DAYS_OF_WORKS,default= "LV")
    hour_init = models.TimeField()
    hour_end = models.TimeField()
```

This is the search for the object I do. Those with a radius equal to 50. Now how can I access another attribute of the model?

```
response=item.objects.filter(radius=data)
response.hour_end
```

for example how can I acces to: hour_end atribute? because if I write response.hour_end gives me error

Answer (score 1):

when your using filter method, actually your are accessing to a queryset ( not a single object ). that's because if you use response.hour_end, you'll get error

you have 3 options:

1 - use forloop in template to achieve each object hour_end in template:

```
{% for response in response %}
    {{ response.hour_end }}
{% endfor %}
```

2 - use get method with a specific attr like id :

```
response.get(id=id)
response.hour_end
```

3- use forloop in view like in template:

```
for response in response:
    response_date = print(response.hour_end)
```